# Droid Explorer does not recognize Android Studio as a valid Android SDK during install.

Tags: android-sdk, droid-explorer

Trying to install droid explorer on a Win7 laptop.

To get Droid Explorer installed and working, do I need to:
1. Install older version of Android SDK?
2. Wait for Droid Explorer to catch up?
3. Do something tricky and undocumented?

Thanks in advance to all who answer.
Bill

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of Droid Explorer.*

I do not use the Android Studio SDK, nor do I have it installed. But what I can tell you is the following:

To be considered a valid android SDK for Droid Explorer to use, it has to meet the following criteria:

- `adb.exe` must exist in the `/sdk-path/platform-tools` directory

  - It can also exist in `/sdk-path/tools` directory, as this is where it originally was located.
- in `/sdk-path/platforms` there must be at least 1 platform. It will be named something like *android-23*.
- Droid Explorer installer will check `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Android SDK Tools\`. If it finds a value there, it will set that as the initial directory of the SDK. It will still verify the tools in the directory.
- Droid Explorer will also check that `aapt.exe exists in the /sdk-path/build-tools` directory.

If Android Studio SDK does not meet these requirements, then it will not validate the SDK as valid. These checks are made because Droid Explorer uses these tools, and even others in these directories.

The best way to get Droid Explorer to work is to install the SDK using the official SDK installer. You can set up Android Studio to use that path for the SDK.

Comment: Thank you, Ryan.
So in short, the answer at this time is to separately install an older version of the Android SDK, and point DroidExplorer to that.

Since as of Marshmallow the Android Studio is claiming that the older layout of the SDK is no longer the 'official' (whatever they mean by that) development platform, are there any plans to update DroidExplorer for the new SDK installation?

Comment: Why would you have to install an older version of the SDK? What I am saying is currently, Droid Explorer does not support the SDK that is installed with Android Studio, the only officially supported SDK is the Standalone install of the SDK. If you have an issue with 2 versions of the SDK, then you can have Android Studio use the SDK that is installed by the standalone installer.

Comment: Ahhh, So I was not aware that the layout changed in SDK for 5. I will look in to what has changed and will make changes to support that. So, since that is the case, yes, currently, the latest SDK is not supported.

Comment: Thanks again for the clarification, Ryan.
My confusion is due to the statements made when downloading the Android SDK via https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html, which is where the claim is made "If you have been using Eclipse with ADT, be aware that Android Studio is now the official IDE for Android, so you should migrate to Android Studio to receive all the latest IDE updates.". I now notice it says nothing about the SDK. Thanks again for your answers.

Comment: ok, great. And I will look in to installing the Android Studio and see what is different about the SDK and see if I can add support for that in the future as well.

Comment: And i the meantime, I'll install the standalone SDK and see if I can make further progress.
Best regards, and this looks like a very promising tool for the things I have planned.

Comment: Surprise: Android Studio locates the SDK under %UserHome%\AppData\Local\Android\SDK.